# Avoid sql join for a specific table row

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my asp.net mvc application, 
I have a table called "Preference" and this table will always have only one row for the application preferences (again this table can not include more than one row).

I always make left join with Preference table when I want to query any other table, as an example, If I want to return all customers. I have to make left join with Preference table to check if I need to return customers full name or not, or to check if I need to return active customers, etc.

As you know, left join has a performance cost, especially when I need to use it in each query; So, Is there are any other way that allows me to take these preferences one time? (eg. when application start) and don't use the left join; although I need to be able to update these preferences each time update them in database(from the control panel of app).

I need a solution that does not have any cost regarding performance, So I am not recommending the session solution very much.

What do you suggest?

Comment: Don't worry about that left join's performance cost.

Comment: Why? I know it is join only one row in performance table, but I mostly do the join for most of table (customers, orders, invoices,...)

Comment: So I think it is better to avoid left join, but is the session could give better performance.

Answer (score 4):

You could use singleton class which has two methods get and set.
Call set every time when you change preferences.
And depend on values form get method build your query (whether active or not, full name or not).

Comment: @simply-ged No, Because I use the same web app for many databases, in other words, each customer has a subdomain that joined with his database, by use singleton all users will share the same object which is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just do INNER JOIN - in most situations it has better performance. You could even do cartesian or cross join (without condition on join) if you are certain that preferences has exacly 1 row.

Answer (score 1):

there are a number of ways this can be solved.

One way would be this:

on application start, load the row from the database and cache it. Every time you need a value from it, retrieve it from the cache.

Now, let's assume that the application settings are changed via your admin panel. Once they are saved, clear that cached value and reload it from your database.
There is no reason to keep joining in your database basically.

Comment: Good, but all customers use the same web application but with different databases, while each customer has a sub-domain that refer to his database, but the web app is one, So here maybe I need to cache in memory or on user client?

Comment: Could you elaborate more please

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a Singleton service that loads the table on startup and is used to store any values when they are updated (via your control panel). You can inject that service into any controller that needs access to the data and the controller would not need to access the database because the service would keep the data in memory.